# Is using "than with" to connect an independent clause to a dependent clause is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, writing

> "Human processor model of interaction, in cognitive psychology, views the user as another computer in the system. In this model, the user is like a computer processor that takes input from the system and gives an output. This model of the interaction between a user and a computer is used to analyze the efficiency with which the user can interact with the system. It is concerned with how fast the user can perform the action, **than with**, whether the actions are understandable to the user. For example, how fast can the user log in to his account? It is not concerned with whether the login process makes sense to the user."

Hi, everyone. In recent days, I have become interested in writing, and thus, I try to proofread all my work for clarity and grammar. I am writing my assignment and this is the first paragraph that I have edited till now. The problem is with the sentence highlighted in bold. Specifically, with connecting the independent clause "It is concerned with how fast the user can perform the action" to the dependent clause "whether the actions are understandable to the user". I used "than with" to contrast these two clauses. So, firstly, I am not sure if "than with" works here (and whether I should use commas before and after "than with"), and secondly, if other words would make much more sense and why?

If there are other grammatical issues with this post , and if you want to point those out, please do. It would help.

Comment: There's nothing visible in bold. By the way, no need for all the phatic communication introducing yourself. Just state the question and what you need answering. It takes time to read, and adds nothing.

Comment: Hi, Prime Mover. Thanks for pointing that out. I will omit needless words before posting from now on.

Comment: Your sentence is not acceptable. One solution is to add the word "more" before "concerned".  Subordinate clauses don't normally connect an independent clause to an dependent one; rather, the former are normally embedded within some larger clause called the matrix clause. In your ex. "than" and "with" are preps, so we have the PP "than with whether the actions are ..., with the embedded PP "with whether the actions are understandable ..." as complement of "than". The subordinate clause is the interrogative "whether the actions are ... " which is complement of "with". No commas are required.

Comment: In other words "than with" should not be considered to be a 'connector', since it's not a constituent, but a marker of two preposition phrases, one embedded within the other.

Comment: Thanks BillJ. Your comment clarified why the sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the fact that, until you hit the "than with", there is nothing in the sentence (or indeed, in the paragraph) that indicates you are about to introduce an antithesis.

You might want to say something like:

"Rather than seeking to answer the question as to whether the actions are understandable to the user, it is (more) concerned with how fast the user can perform the action."

But even then, the thought comes very much out of left-field unless the essay has already introduced the idea that the two concepts need to be considered as separate (and competing) requirements for design consideration.

Or perhaps:

"It is **more** concerned with how fast the user can perform the action, than with whether the actions are understandable to the user" for a minimal change.

Comment: Or "rather than with",

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not at all thought about it in terms of the whole structure. I will rewrite.